# Runtime error using Python 2.7 IDLE for Windows?

Tags: python, windows-xp

Every time I run my code in Python IDLE development environment, I get a Visual C++ runtime error/unhandled exception in pythonw.exe.

```
Figure 1: pythonw.exe - Application Error
The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred 
in the application at location 0x1e0e1379.
```

I am using networkx and matplotlib to display a graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
```

I am running Windows XP.
Any ideas how to resolve this? Or should I just quit using IDLE?

Comment: You should quit using IDLE, regardless of any errors.

Comment: `python "Desktop\myscript.py"` should do it as well.

Comment: Is IDLE frowned on? It does seem a little useless. I'll probably just stick with Notepad2 and a command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was indeed to quit using IDLE. I got the Python stuff for Eclipse; I'd recommend that setup.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix for this is to open IDLE from the start menu and then opening your code files from there.